# MFC Threading Issue - The program doesnt end after all threads are completed

Tags: multithreading, mfc

I have created a Single Dialog application which basically does a series of complex calculation. The application was first created as a Win32 console application and later I decided to add a progressbar and then I converted the console application to a Single Dialog based application. The dialog has a progressbar on it. in OnInitDialog() function of the dialog, I start the calculations. The calculations are running on a worker thread. This thread is created by calling _beginthreadex function. The progressbar is updated by the thread by posting messages to the Dialog by using PostMessage. After the thread has completed execution,  I call CDialog::OnOK() function to close the dialog. The issue is that, even after the dialog is closed, the application is not end immediately. It takes nearly 2 seconds to close the application even though the dialog is closed.
Any help to solve this issue is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hit break in the debugger after the dialog has closed. In what code does the debugger break? What threads are active?

Comment: Are there any memory leaks reported on the Output tab of VisualStudio after the application quits (as Debug build)? This can take also a while.

Comment: @xml-tools: yeah, you are right. There are some memory leaks reported. I shall look into them and try fixing them. Thanks.

Comment: @CadPro you are welcome. so I will post an answer for you saying "fix your memory leaks first" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your worker thread is still running. The application will not terminate until all threads are finished running.  Since your UI thread closes before the worker thread, the window may be hidden, but the process does not terminate until the worker thread has completed its work.

Answer (score 0):

The worker thread might be still running. To make sure that the thread is stopped use events to signal . you can signal an event to kill the thread when the user presses close button in the dialog.

You can check whether the event is signaled inside your complex calculation (may be a loop) and break from it. Thus stopping the thread without any issues.

```
while(true)
{
  //Some complex task

   DWORD dwWaitResult;
   dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hwndShutdownEvent,0);
   if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == dwWaitResult)   
   {
        break;                  
   }
}
```

Comment: No, this is not the case. All my worker threads are end. The issue is with memory leak. Anyway thanks for your time